# I've lost my root status

Tags: root, password-recovery

I created a new user and set its option to "root". Then I switched the option of the user which was activated to "standard" and closed the window. But now I can't login as the new user because I didn't set a password and so the user which is root is not activated. What shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

Does GRUB show you the recovery mode? If yes, select it, and then `root console`. Now type `mount -o rw,remount /`, then `passwd <ReplaceByUsername>`. Now enter the new password twice and reboot.

If you don't see GRUB, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> (depends on your system), or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> during boot.

If even this doesn't work, boot a Ubuntu Live System and do the following things:

1. Enter `sudo fdisk -l` and search the partition with "Linux" system
2. Mount this partition: `sudo mkdir /media/sdXX && sudo mount /dev/sdXX /media/sdXX` (Replace the Xes by the values in the partition file name)
3. Now login as root user on your installed system: `sudo chroot /media/sdXX`
4. Type `passwd <ReplaceByUsername>`
5. Reboot your installed system and you should be fine.